# Any stats on how many Area51 proposals have changed/widened their scope?

Tags: discussion, area-51, scope

I know that finding the right granularity for a proposal is tough. I'm wondering if the Powers-that-be have any information on how many proposals have *changed* (presumably to be wider in scope), and thereby increased their number of followers?

Personally, after I proposed a Blender software site, it didn't do so hot - so I widened the scope to all 3D modelling software, and it did - slightly better... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're still discussing how to deal with **merging smaller proposals** at this point.

My idea was if enough high rep (2k) users vote for a merge then every committer is emailed and has to say yea or nay to the merge. If at least, say 50 percent, on each side agree this is a valid merge then we merge them.

I think the committers have to agree as only they have the required domain knowledge to determine if this is a valid merge or not.

Comment: What if the smaller proposal is a duplicate? http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10961/weight-loss Can these be merged by a moderator?

Comment: I really don't think it takes much domain knowledge to know that *barefoot running* is a very **limited** subset of *running*, despite the proposer's claim that it's "specialized enough to merit its own discussion." But hey, I don't run barefoot, I could be wrong... :)

Answer (score 0):

I have an example of the inverse: my [writing proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1623/writing?referrer=Z8tkS8wAiM81) was originally called "Books and Writing", but the audience seemed to be very different, so I dropped the "books" part and it got to commitment phase anyway.

Then a [books proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6426/books?referrer=kRRgWviybzU1) was created to cover what it was left out there (this one still needs more followers though).